# CakePHP Recursive not working with loadModel and this->set

Tags: php, cakephp, recursion, cakephp-model

Recursion does not seem to be working when I use $this->loadModel, I want to say I remember something about having to explicitly set the belongsTo and hasMany in this situation, but that seems anti-cakephp-auto-magical, I have yet to find any answers stating how to use

```
$this->loadModel
```

and

```
$this->...->find('all', array('recursive' => 2));
```

any ideas on why this isnt working is greatly appreciated.

```
$this->loadModel('DeployablesJoin');
$deployablesJoins = $this->DeployablesJoin->find('all', array('recursive' => 2));

$this->loadModel('DeployablesComplete');
$deployablesCompletes = $this->DeployablesComplete->find('all', array('recursive' => 2, 'conditions' => array('successful' => array('0', '-1'))));

$this->set('deployablesCompletes', $deployablesCompletes);
$this->set('deployablesJoins', $deployablesJoins);
```

Edit: Full Code Below

My DeployablesJoin Model

```
class DeployablesJoin extends NodeCncAppModel {

    public $actsAs = array('Containable');

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Deployable' => array(
            'className' => 'Deployable',
            'foreignKey' => 'deployable_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => 'title,filename,created',
            'order' => ''
        ),
        'ServerClass' => array(
            'className' => 'ServerClass',
            'foreignKey' => 'server_class_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => 'name',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
}
```

Relevant part of the controller

```
    $this->loadModel('DeployablesJoin');
    $deployablesJoins = $this->DeployablesJoin->find('all');

    print_r($deployablesJoins); die();
```

Results from print_r/die

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [DeployablesJoin] => Array ( 
            [id] => 1 
            [deployable_id] => 5 
            [server_class_id] => 1 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

What I have found that does work is the following (relevant part controller)

```
$this->loadModel('DeployablesJoin');
$this->DeployablesJoin->belongsTo = array(
    'Deployable' => array(
        'className' => 'Deployable',
        'foreignKey' => 'deployable_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => 'title,filename,created',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'ServerClass' => array(
        'className' => 'ServerClass',
        'foreignKey' => 'server_class_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => 'name',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
$deployablesJoins = $this->DeployablesJoin->find('all');

print_r($deployablesJoins); die();
```

Results from print_r/die

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [DeployablesJoin] => Array ( 
            [id] => 1 
            [deployable_id] => 5 
            [server_class_id] => 1 
        ) 
        [Deployable] => Array ( 
            [title] => asdf 
            [filename] => 5_agent.zip 
            [created] => 2015-01-09 21:31:25 
        ) 
       [ServerClass] => Array ( 
            [name] => Crawler 
       ) 
 )
```

When I do a print_r/die on $this->DeployablesJoin, I get the following

```
AppModel Object
(
    [useDbConfig] => default
    [useTable] => deployables_joins
    [id] => 
    ...
    [table] => deployables_joins
    [primaryKey] => id
    ...
    [name] => DeployablesJoin
    [alias] => DeployablesJoin
    [tableToModel] => Array
        (
            [deployables_joins] => DeployablesJoin
        )

    [cacheQueries] => 
    [belongsTo] => Array
        (
        )
```

Comment: I am going to look in the core and see whats up with this belongsTo and why it appears to not be loading that array

Comment: This is for sure a problem with belongsTo, see recent edit

Comment: Don't use recursive, use explicit contain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any reason your 'recursive' would not be working other than the associations set up incorrectly.  I would suggest verifying those.

That being said, using recursive 2 is considered bad practice.  Instead, set recursive to `-1`, and use CakePHP's amazing Containable Behavior to retrieve any additional information.

Another "best practice" change would be to put your finds into model methods instead of in the Controllers.  So, in your case, it would be something like this:

```
// in the controller
$this->loadModel('DeployablesJoin');
$deployablesJoins =  $this->DeployableJoin->getAll();

//in the DeployablesJoin model
public function getAll() {
    $this->recursive = 2; // should change this to containable instead though
    return $this->find('all');
}
```

Comment: I get Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'getAll' at line 1

Comment: I think thats gettings pretty close, but no cigar

Comment: That error likely means you don't have the method available in the correct model.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the model I am trying to load is in a plugin, and I did not specify the plugin in loadModel like so ...

```
$this->loadModel('NodeCnc.DeployablesJoin');
```

I would have caught this earlier, however, with the following, it was still returning results

```
$this->loadModel('DeployablesJoin');
```

I am going to submit two patches, one to load the model without the plugin portion, and one to throw an error when loaded without a plugin and see which gets acccepted.

Comment: I just got caught out by this simple gotcha, thanks for the sanity check Jeffrey!